# How to start with GCC/GNU

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, gnu, stm32

Not long I started to program in C on Embedded Systems. So far I have been using an IDE (*MDK-Keil*). Unfortunately I reached code size limit. This forces me to switch from the commercial ARM compiler to a free product, such as the GCC.

As already noted, I'm still at high school and so my overall knowledge about Unix/Linux, programming languages and paradigms and especially how computers work is very limited.

My goals are:

- Squeeze my C code into my *STM32* devices...no matter how!
- Have an overview of what is Cygwin, MinGW, GNU, GCC, how to write Makefiles and how it works under the hood if I compile my C code, link it etc.

To cut the chase...

- I want the knowledge of a full-blown electrical engineer/computer scientist

What is my starting point?

- I know most syntactical elements of the C language and already wrote several a bit of code.
- I know most of the Cortex M instructions and have a rough understanding what they do.

What I'm actually looking for, is a guide that takes me through the wonderful world of computers, and shows me step by step how things work, as I feel pretty lost and have no idea where to start to learn the mentioned things above.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is off-topic here; it is far too broad. Just some notes: there is no need to use Eclipse or any other IDE with gcc. An editor and a console are sufficient. `make` is widely used, but there are easier and more flexible build-tools. Not sure why you mention Cygwin and MinGW. They are for Windows and not related to embedded systems programming. Finally: Ubuntu and its derivates (Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc.) have ready configured packages for `arm-none-eabi` development; no need to manually build them.

Comment: "it is far too broad" Sry for that. As I mentioned before, my main problems is that I dont know where to start. How shall I make a precise question, If I not even know what I need to know. "Not sure why you mention Cygwin and MinGW". thought, this has some importance, when using gcc on windows, but it seams that this isnt a good idea?

Comment: Please google! You are supposed to show some effort on your own before asking a question anyway.

Comment: Well then I guess you met someone who isnt able to do that successfully.

Comment: Too broad for SO. Suggest you look [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)

Comment: It's two years later and I'm currently studying electrical engineering. Before I reach the state of most SO users, where I think, that I'm born with a keyboard in my hands, I wanted to rewrite this questions and give a hopefully helpful answer for upcoming computer scientists, despite knowing, that this question is almost the definition of off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on programming, switch over to linux, it's simply superior, and also, it's really simple to use a package manager to install GCC. If you're a beginner who's uncomfortable with command line stuff, start with linux mint or Ubuntu.
Once you've got that down, do this-

1. Get the arm-none-eabi version of GCC

   Go look at the datasheet.

   Get the stm32cube package, it has a lot of inbuilt startup code, and HALs(Hardware abstraction Libraries, personally, not my choice since I like to have the utmost control)

   Write a system.c file where you setup all the clocks needed for initial operation. Here's mine.

   Integrate the headers by making a proper makefile

   Get coding :P

Now, I'm gonna make this clear, I've never used the HAL (the thing where you pass structs) simply because it feels stupid. So you might need to do a bit more work if you're planning to use it.

Comment: That STlib "HAL" is plain rubbish. It only complicates the code and binds the programmer to the vendor. Much like the - incompatible - similar approaches of the other vendors. After they cannot differentiate by the CPU core, they now try by the software.

Comment: Ok, thx that was a bit what I hoped for. Actually I'm already very familiar with STM32.  Personally I also dont like the Cube neither, I miss the old Standard Peripheral Library. But Hal is somewhat useful if you work with RTOS and code fficiancy isnt that important. Anyway If you have some information about where to start reading (documentation etc.) I would be thankful.

Comment: @Olaf Well, yes, but the startup file included which isn't in anyway related to the HAL and the pin definitions are included which make life easier. I hate the HAL too. Seems convoluted and takes away control.

Comment: @Aresloom What documentation specifically? If it's gcc we're talking about then there isn't much problem. Just use google.

Comment: @ShaheAnsar: Well, writing your own startup isn't that complicated (you can even use C on the Cortex-M). And once you have your own with some flexibility, you can use that for the other Cortex-M MCUs, too. Which leaves the MCU headers. Yes, they are necessary; I wouldn't want to write my own. But even there you have to correct the errors&flaws first.

Comment: There is a reason such questions are OT here. Your answer cannot be complete enough for beginners.

Comment: @Aresloom This is a good example of how you'd want to do it - `arm-none-eabi-gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mlittle-endian -mthumb -I/home/shahe/ARM/projects/CMSIS/Include/ -I/home/shahe/ARM/projects/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F1xx/Include/ -I/home/shahe/ARM/projects/ -DSTM32F103xB  -c main.c -o main.o` You might wanna download the cube package because it contains the linker script which saves you work.Btw, ike I've written above, you might wanna include the header files containing the pin definitions if you're not keen on making a billion structs. I can't help you much with the HAL though.

Comment: @Olaf The startup code is easy, so is the linker script, but I doubt any beginner would want to do that. Also, pin definitons are the only reason I even downloaded that thing, which can be a compelling reason for anyone who isn't interested in writing boring code...

Comment: @Aresloom Btw, I forgot to mention this, but you might wanna check OpenOCD and gdb. They're essential if you want to do debugging on gcc

Comment: @ShaheAnsar With Keil I wrote many of the the pin definitions, registers myself. As you can write in the Code (the text editor is still open) its very easy, as you can just copy paste the adresses from the peripheral window into your code.
"What documentation specifically?" About gcc etc. I started with something like that now http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html#templates
olaf "Your answer cannot be complete enough for beginners." Without offence. How would you ask a question about this topic if you were in my situation?

Comment: @Aresloom You forgot to put the @ before Olaf. As for the documention, I'd advise you to check out the official gcc docs - [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/). This should have **EVERYTHING** you need

Comment: @ShaheAnsar Not allowed to notify more the one user. Ok, thank you I'll try that.

Comment: @Olaf "Your answer cannot be complete enough for beginners." Without offence. How would you ask a question about this topic if you were in my situation?

Comment: @Aresloom: None taken. As you ask: I would accept this off-topic as I told you already and try elsewhere. You already got some information from this answer; leave it at that and don't use comments to add additional questions. Site-rules are there for good reason, stack overflow is a Q&/A site, not a forum or tutorial site.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very long way to go, to become comfortable with the things mentioned in the question, and so it is not possible to give a precise answer here.

Still I found that the book

**[David A. Patterson und John L. Hennessy: Computer Organization and Design](http://ac.aua.am/Arm/Public/2017-Spring-Computer-Organization/Textbooks/ComputerOrganizationAndDesign5thEdition2014.pdf)**

does an amazing job if you want to start to learn about computers.